# graph theory,planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

i have a simple planar graph $G$ with $6$ vertices,$4$ vertices of degree $4$. Why $G$ doesn't have a vertex with degree of $5$?

I know it's suppose to be a simple question but IM clueless and cant find a way to deal with it ,I tried to show that $G$ contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ graph but without any success so far ,thanks to all the helpers

Comment: Do not order us to prove.  This is a question and answer site.  so if you have a question, state it as a question. Also, please ask one question at a time.  [Please read ASAP](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|132.0576), and use some suggestions there, to improve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the graph has a vertex of degree $5$.

Then it is connected so it is true that

$$e \le 3v-6 \implies e \leq 12$$

but $$\sum_{v \in V} deg(v) =5+4\cdot 4+x = 21+x = 2e$$ where $x$ is the degree of the vertex with not specified degree, then $x = 1$ or $x=3$ .

If $x=1$ then this means the four vertices of degree $4$ have to form $K_4$ and it's easy to see that $K_4$ with all the four vertices connected to another vertex is $K_{5}$.

Instead if $x=3$ you can easily draw the graph and see that all choices are bound and you will obtain again a supergraph of (an expansion of) $K_{5}$

Comment: why 3 is not an option for x? + how do you know that k4 combined with 1 vertex is a supergraph of k3.3 i cant see it , thank you for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: you are awesome thank you very much

Comment: Too good!! (it was $K_5$ anyway :P)